# How to get the text of a textarea with a prototype click event?

Tags: javascript, text, click, prototype

There are several textareas on my page and I need the text of the one someone is clicking on. I would know how to do it in jQuery but I need a prototype/javascript solution. What I tried so far:

```
$$("textarea").each(function (el) {
      el.observe('click', respondToClick);
      function respondToClick(event) {
         var element = Event.element(event);
         var text = element.innerHTML();
         console.log(text);
      }
});
```

There are no errors in the console but also not the text I need. So how to get it?

**EDIT:** 
That's the solution. I forgot the document.ready-equivalent in prototype and thanks to bruchowski I could edit the correct prototype method to get the text:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function () {
     $$("textarea").each(function (el) {
          el.observe('click', respondToClick);
          function respondToClick(event) {
              var element = Event.element(event);
              var text = element.value;
              console.log(text);
          }
     });
});
```

P.S.: Prototype Vesion is 1.7.0

Comment: I belive `.value` is the property you want to access

Comment: Thx! That and adding document.observe("dom:loaded", function () {...} worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Form.Element.getValue()](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Form/Element/getValue/index.html), or its [$F()](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar-F/index.html) alias:

```
 var element = Event.element(event);
 var text = $F(element);
 console.log(text);
```

Comment: yeah thx. That worked too. I didn't get any errors because I forgot to add document.observe("dom:loaded", function () {...} so I didn't get any errors and was confused. But now everything works fine